# Splitting of free groups

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let's assume there are two epiomorphisms (with non-trivial kernels) $f_1,f_2$ from nonabelian finitely-generated free group $f_i:F \rightarrow G$ into arbitrary finitely generated group. From the property of free groups I can lift $f_1$ to $g:F \rightarrow F$, which gives me a commuting triangle. In what situation can I say that there exists a finite index subgroup $H <F$ with an isomorphism $\varphi: T * I \rightarrow H$ such that $g \circ \varphi $ takes $I$ isomorphically to an image of $g$ ? Thank you for all your answers

Comment: What are $T$ and $I$? They have not been quantified in your question.

Comment: some free groups

Comment: So essentially you are asking whether some finite index subgroup $H<F$ has some free factorization $H=T*I$ such that $g$ takes $I$ isomorphically to $g(F)$?

Comment: yes, exactly, that's what I'm asking

Comment: This is true, but, the scenario you described from which $g$ arises is irrelevant: for *any* homomorphism $g : F_1 \to F_2$ between two finite rank free groups $F_1,F_2$, there exists a finite index subgroup $H < F_1$ and a free factorization $H = T * I$ such that $g$ maps $I$ isomorphically to $g(F_1)$. The proof uses Stallings fold methods, and it's not a hard exercise if you've some some Stallings fold proofs. I can write out some details of the proof if you like.

Comment: No, thank you. I've already found some decent referalls.